# Coloring quiver vectors in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have 4 vectors, first threes are complex numbers and 4th one is summation of them.

I plot them with quiver successfully, however, I need to color 4th one as red. How can I color only 4th one to red?

```
% vectors I want to plot as rows (XSTART, YSTART) (XDIR, YDIR)
rays = [
  0 0   real(X1) imag(X1) ;
  0 0   real(X2) imag(X2) ;
  0 0   real(X3) imag(X3) ;
  0 0   real(SUM) imag(SUM) ;
] ;

% quiver plot
quiver(rays( :,1 ), rays( :,2 ), rays( :,3 ), rays( :,4 ));

% set interval
axis([-30 30 -30 30]);
```

or shall i use plotv ? https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/plotv.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `handle` returned by `quiver` function does not allow to access to each single  element in order to change its properties, in this case, the colour.

A possible work around, although not exactly elegant, could be to:

- plot the quiver for the whole set of data
- remove from the axes the `u`, `v`, `x` and `y` data of the element you want to change the colour
- set `hold on`
- plot again the `quiver` for the whole set of data
- remove from the axes the `u`, `v`, `x` and `y` data of the element you do not want to change the colour
- set the desired colour to the remainig item

A possible implementation of the proposed approach could be:

```
% Generate some data
rays = [
  0 0   rand-0.5 rand-0.5 ;
   0 0  rand-0.5 rand-0.5 ;
   0 0  rand-0.5 rand-0.5 ;
] ;
rays(4,:)=sum(rays)

% Plot the quiver for the whole matrix (to be used to check the results
figure
h_orig=quiver(rays( :,1 ), rays( :,2 ), rays( :,3 ), rays( :,4 ));
grid minor
% Plot the quiver for the whole matrix
figure
% Plot the quiver for the whole set of data
h0=quiver(rays( :,1 ), rays( :,2 ), rays( :,3 ), rays( :,4 ));
% Get the u, v, x, y data
u=get(h0,'udata')
v=get(h0,'vdata')
x=get(h0,'xdata')
y=get(h0,'ydata')
% Delete the data of the last element
set(h0,'udata',u(1:end-1),'vdata',v(1:end-1),'xdata', ...
   x(1:end-1),'ydata',y(1:end-1))
% Set hold on
hold on
% Plot again the quiver for the whole set of data
h0=quiver(rays( :,1 ), rays( :,2 ), rays( :,3 ), rays( :,4 ));
% Delete the u, v, x, y data of the element you do not want to change the
% colour
set(h0,'udata',u(end),'vdata',v(end),'xdata', ...
   x(end),'ydata',y(end))
% Set the desired colour to the remaining object
h0.Color='r'
grid minor
```

[image]

Hope this helps,

Qapla'